# how to bind data to DropDownList through client side using WCF service

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, wcf

I am new to WCF services. I want to use WCF service in ASP.NET to bind data to a `DropDownList` through jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a simple `$.ajax(..)` call
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

In WCF you can create Rest Service (return JSON) and consume this JSON response in jQuery

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/dd547388

Lots of example in internet.

Sample in c# (Atom feeds):

```
   [ServiceContract]
   public interface INewsFeed
   {
      [OperationContract]
      [WebGet]
      Atom10FeedFormatter GetFeeds();
   }

    public class NewsFeed : INewsFeed
    {
          public Atom10FeedFormatter GetFeeds()
          {
          SyndicationFeed feed = new SyndicationFeed("My Blog Feed", "This is a test feed", new Uri("http://SomeURI"));
           feed.Authors.Add(new SyndicationPerson("someone@microsoft.com"));
           feed.Categories.Add(new SyndicationCategory("How To Sample Code"));
           feed.Description = new TextSyndicationContent("This is a how to sample that demonstrates how to expose a feed using RSS with WCF");

          SyndicationItem item1 = new SyndicationItem(
             "Lorem ipsum",
             "Lorem ipsum",
             new Uri("http://localhost/Content/One"),
             "ItemOneID",
             DateTime.Now);

         List<SyndicationItem> items = new List<SyndicationItem>();  
         items.Add(item1); 
         feed.Items = items;   
         return new Atom10FeedFormatter(feed);
          }
    }
```

and in svc you just need to add (**Factory** part):

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="RssReader.Wcf.NewsFeed" CodeBehind="NewsFeed.svc.cs" Factory=System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory%>
```

**Edited:**

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
          <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior>
              <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
              <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
              <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
              <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
            </behavior>
          </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Important part is  `<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>` in that scenario you don't need to define any endpoints

Comment: thanks buddy i am also want to know is there any configuration needed in webconfig file?

Comment: thanks for your reply is there any simple example with WCF . i am only learner . i want some easy examples ...

Comment: Look at the webcasts on Channel9